# Spring boot. The profit of using @ConfigurationProperties annotation

Tags: java, spring, configuration, annotations

Could you explain me the profit of using @ConfigurationProperties annotation.

I have to options of my code.

First with @ConfigurationProperties annotation:

```
@Service
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="myApp")
public class myService() {
  private int myProperty;
  public vois setMyProperty(int myProperty) {
    this.myProperty = myProperty;
  }
  // And this I can use myProperty which was injected from application.properties (myApp.myProperty = 10)
}
```

The second one without @ConfigurationProperties annotation.

It looks like this:

```
@Service
public class myService() {
    private final Environment environment;
    public myService(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }
  // And this I can use myProperty which was injected from application.properties (myApp.myProperty = 10)
  environment.getProperty("myApp.myProperty")
}
```

With one property the amount of code looks the same, but if I have about 10 properties, the first options will have more boilerplate of code (define 10 properties and 10 setters for this properties).

The second options will have the one injection of Environment and no addition boilerplate code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@ConfigurationProperties` is used when you want to map a set of properties from properties file with a Class properties. Using `@ConfigurationProperties` make your code more readable, categorized / modular and cleaner. How?

1. You have application properties mapped to a POJO bean & ensures re-usability.
2. You are using the spring bean with abstraction (properties are automatically injected).

Now if you use `Environment` bean, you will always have to call `getProperty` and then specify the string name of the property, so lots of boilerplate code. Also, if you have to refactor some property and rename it you have to do it in all places it's being used in.

Hence, my recommendation is when you have to group properties and re-use in multiple places go for `@ConfigurationProperties`. If you have to use a property or two and only in one place throughout application then Environment can be used.

Answer (score 0):

**@ConfigurationProperties** is annotation for externalized configuration. To inject property value from a property file to a class, we can add **@ConfigurationProperties** at a class level

Answer (score 0):

When using `ConfigurationProperties` you don't need to remember the property name to retrieve it. Spring takes care of the mapping. For eg:

`app.properties.username-max-length` in properties

will be mapped to

`String usernameMaxLength` in POJO

You just need to get `usernameMaxLength` field name right, once.

Using `ConfigurationProperties` makes your code easy to test. You can have multiple properties file for different test scenarios and can use them in your tests with `TestPropertySource("path")`.

Now, if boilerplate `getters`/`setters` bothers you. You can always use [lombok's](https://projectlombok.org/) `@Getter`/`@Setter`. This is just a suggestion and depends on an individual's choice.

***Also, starting from [Spring Boot 2.2.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes), your `@ConfigurationProperties` classes can be immutable***

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.properties")
public class AppProperties {

    private final Integer usernameMaxLength;

    @ConstructorBinding
    public AppProperties(Integer usernameMaxLength) {

        this.usernameMaxLength = usernameMaxLength;
    }

    // Getters
}
```